# SpingBoot Mapping not working. 404 status

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am following a tutorial on youtube step by step but I am not getting a result. The code is as follows:

Main Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

model class

```
public class Greeting {

    private BigInteger id;
    private String text;

    public Greeting() {}

    public BigInteger getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(BigInteger id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Greeting Controller

```
@RestController()
public class GreetingController {

    private static BigInteger nextId;
    private static Map<BigInteger, Greeting> greetingMap;

    private static Greeting save(Greeting greeting) {
        if (greetingMap == null) {

            greetingMap = new HashMap<BigInteger, Greeting>();
            nextId = BigInteger.ONE;
        }
        greeting.setId(nextId);
        nextId = nextId.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        greetingMap.put(greeting.getId(), greeting);
        return greeting;
    }

    static {
        Greeting g1 = new Greeting();
        g1.setText("Hello World");
        save(g1);
        Greeting g2 = new Greeting();
        g2.setText("Hola Mundo!");
        save(g2);
    }

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/api/greetings",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Greeting>> getGreetings() {
        Collection<Greeting> greetings = greetingMap.values();

        return new ResponseEntity<Collection<Greeting>>(greetings, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Pom.xml file

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.hakeem.webservice2</groupId>
<artifactId>WebService2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Whenever I run a get request, I get this response from Postman:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1439128293727,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/greetings"
}
```

or the following from chrome:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Sun Aug 09 08:43:41 COT 2015
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>   No message available

I followed the videos step by step. The tutor on the video has seemingly not done anything additional.
Whenever I type in

> localhost:8080/api/greetings

All I get is the aforementioned error.

Addition. This is the console output I do not know if it will be helpful:

> 2015-08-09 10:49:09.918  INFO 7696 --- [           main] com.hakeem.webservice2.Application       : Starting Application on Laptop with PID 7696 (C:\Users\HakeemAbdussamad\Documents\MarsWorkspace\WebService2\target\classes started by HakeemAbdussamad in C:\Users\HakeemAbdussamad\Documents\MarsWorkspace\WebService2)
>   2015-08-09 10:49:09.988  INFO 7696 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7bb0e64a: startup date [Sun Aug 09 10:49:09 COT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
>   2015-08-09 10:49:10.710  INFO 7696 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
>   2015-08-09 10:49:11.547  INFO 7696 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
>   2015-08-09 10:49:11.797  INFO 7696 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
>   2015-08-09 10:49:11.801  INFO 7696 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.15
>   2015-08-09 10:49:11.926  INFO 7696 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
>   2015-08-09 10:49:11.926  INFO 7696 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1942 ms
>   2015-08-09 10:49:12.743  INFO 7696 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
>   2015-08-09 10:49:12.747  INFO 7696 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
>   2015-08-09 10:49:12.747  INFO 7696 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
>   2015-08-09 10:49:12.963  INFO 7696 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7bb0e64a: startup date [Sun Aug 09 10:49:09 COT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
>   2015-08-09 10:49:13.035  INFO 7696 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
>   2015-08-09 10:49:13.036  INFO 7696 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
>   2015-08-09 10:49:13.108  INFO 7696 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
>   2015-08-09 10:49:13.108  INFO 7696 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
>   2015-08-09 10:49:13.191  INFO 7696 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
>   2015-08-09 10:49:13.276  INFO 7696 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
>   2015-08-09 10:49:13.329  INFO 7696 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
>   2015-08-09 10:49:13.331  INFO 7696 --- [           main] com.hakeem.webservice2.Application       : Started Application in 3.733 seconds (JVM running for 4.32)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The given code looks right to my eyes. Looking at the complete source may help. For example - if the `GreetingController` class isn't in the same package or in a subpackage of the `Application` class, it will not be scanned, and so you will have this error.

Comment: Application Greetings and Greetings Controller are in 3 different packages.

Comment: That's the issue, then. You should put all the components (i.e. Controller, Service etc) in the same package or subpackages of the Application class which is annotated with SpringBootApplication. (Otherwise you will have to use @ComponentScan...)

Comment: Thank you. It worked. However, in the video, the tutor said the annotation SpringBootApplication substitutes for three other annotations. Specifically: ComponentScan, EnableAutoConfiguration and Configuration. Did he make a mistake or should his approach work in another context. I asked because his app worked with three different packages. So maybe I am missing something.

Comment: He said it correctly. But ComponentScan by default scans components only in the same package, and subpackages. If you want other packages scanned, you need to pass the packages as parameters to  @ComponentScan.

Comment: Abu, you might like to upvote and/or accept the answer (Click on the up triangle to upvote; on the tick to accept), assuming it helped.

Comment: As a final note, I did not follow the consistent package naming on the tutorial originally. I fixed it by giving my packages consistent names. once I did that, I put the files in different packages and everything worked. Thanks again.