# SpringCloudStream-HttpSource is returning 404

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am working on the Brooklyn.Release version of SpringCloudStream. My use case has HttpSource with Mutiple Sinks. When I added the Starter App dependency to the application and using it as below:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.app</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-http</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

@SpringBootApplication
@Import(HttpSourceConfiguration.class)
public class SourceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SourceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Aggregate App is

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AggregateApplicationBuilder().from(SourceApplication.class)
                .via(ProcessorApplication.class).to(SinkApplication.class).args().run(args);
    }
}
```

Getting the following response as below all the time:

```
<Fault xmlns="http://localhost/">
   <error>Not Found</error>
   <message>No message available</message>
   <path>/</path>
   <status>404</status>
   <timestamp>1477612242743</timestamp>
</Fault>
```

Added ComponentScan for HttpSourceConfiguration(Out of the Box); but no success.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(value = {"com.xxx.xxx.stream","org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.http.source"})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AggregateApplicationBuilder().from(SourceApplication.class)
                .via(ProcessorApplication.class).to(SinkApplication.class).args().run(args);
    }
}
```

If I use the same SourceApplication with Rabbit Binder, it is working as expected. Can you please guide me in getting this working?

Appreciate your help and time.

Regards
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

The REST endpoints don't seem to be setup and it looks like you may be running into this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905357/spingboot-mapping-not-working-404-status). You would need `@ComponentScan` for the package where `HttpSourceConfiguration` is (since it is from a different package).

> If I use the same SourceApplication with Rabbit Binder, it is working as expected.

Do you mean the out of the box `http` app with the rabbit binder or you just added the `rabbit` binder dependency in the above `SourceApplication`?

Usually you prefer using the `http` source application that comes out of the box (with any of the associated binder), but for the aggregate application you don't need the binder unless you have `input` or `output` of the aggregate app itself is bound to a broker.

Comment: I updated the componentScan with no success. I used Rabbit binder as dependency with Separate Spring Boot Apps for Source using HttpSourceConfiguration and Sink (Mongo). I would like to check the performance for the same use case without binder using AggregateApplicationBuilder.

Comment: I am using spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-http as out of the box source along with spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit in case 1 and removed the dependency of spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit in second case.

Comment: I checked the sample code here - [https://github.com/pckeyan/spring-cloud-stream-http-sample-nobinder]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing the repo. I looked at it and found the root cause of the issue. Aggregate application's child apps are not  `web` enabled by default which is why the http endpoints aren't available. Will open an issue at Spring Cloud Stream and follow up. Thanks!

Comment: Thank You, Let me know when I can have the changes to test

Comment: I tried with latest version(Brooklyn.SR2) by enabling WEB but still getting the 404 as http.pathPattern is not getting mapped. can you help please?

Comment: Hi, This is still in PR: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/pull/776. Once this is merged, you are good to go.

Comment: Thank You, Can you let me know when this will be released?